# Term for a person who is extremely dismissive

Tags: single-word-requests, pejorative-language

I'm looking for a word that describes a person who is extremely *dismissive* and unopen to ideas or comments.

**Dismissive**

> feeling or showing that something is unworthy of consideration

---

For example,

> Tom: 'Get your table organised! It's so-'
>
> Jack: 'Shush, bring your comments somewhere else.'

Comment: "Arrogant" (*feeling superiority toward others*) or "cocksure" (*too sure, overconfident*) are possibilities.

Answer (score 3):

My favourite approximant for the word in question is **disdainful**.

[Oxford Languages](https://www.google.com/search?q=disdainful&oq=disdainful&aqs=chrome..69i57j0i433i512l2j0i512l7.2126j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) defines it as follows:

**disdainful**
/dɪsˈdeɪnf(ʊ)l/
*adjective*

showing contempt or lack of respect.

*"with a last disdainful look, she turned towards the door"*

A close second will be the word contemptuous.

[**contemptuous**](https://www.google.com/search?q=contemptuous&sxsrf=AJOqlzWCVH9qxbGfpWaQzMbY9vb5Gzpa4g%3A1675691116476&ei=bAThY97aHLGOmgeGk5fACw&oq=contemt&gs_lcp=Cgxnd3Mtd2l6LXNlcnAQARgBMgcIABCxAxBDMgcIABCxAxBDMgoIABCABBCxAxAKMgQIABBDMgcIABCABBAKMgoIABCABBCxAxAKMgcIABCxAxBDMgcIABCABBAKMgcIABCABBAKMgoIABCABBCxAxAKOgoIABBHENYEELADOgcIABCwAxBDOgQIIxAnOgsIABCABBCxAxCDAToICAAQgAQQsQM6CQgjECcQRhD5AToFCAAQgARKBAhBGABKBAhGGABQ7wdY5w5g7hxoBXAAeACAAZsCiAGoC5IBBTAuNC4zmAEAoAEByAEKwAEB&sclient=gws-wiz-serp)
/kənˈtɛm(p)tʃʊəs/
*adjective*

showing contempt; scornful.

*"she was intolerant and contemptuous of the majority of the human race"*

However, I feel the word parochial has a stronger sense of being close-minded than these words.

**[parochial](https://www.google.com/search?q=parochial&sxsrf=AJOqlzUuD6pa5vRUySDI--qWXehPp_p4fA%3A1675691406377&ei=jgXhY8THFqvCz7sP_LGn4Ac&ved=0ahUKEwjExp74hIH9AhUr4XMBHfzYCXwQ4dUDCA8&uact=5&oq=parochial&gs_lcp=Cgxnd3Mtd2l6LXNlcnAQAzIECCMQJzIICAAQsQMQkQIyBQgAEJECMgoIABCABBCxAxAKMgcIABCABBAKMgcIABCABBAKMgcIABCABBAKMgcIABCABBAKMgcIABCABBAKMgcILhCABBAKOgoIABBHENYEELADOgcIABCwAxBDOgcIIxDqAhAnOgwIABDqAhC0AhBDGAE6FQguEOoCELQCEEMQiwMQqAMQmQMYAToPCAAQ6gIQtAIQQxCLAxgBOgQIABBDOgsILhCDARCxAxCABDoLCAAQgAQQsQMQgwE6BwgAELEDEEM6BQgAEIAEOggILhCABBDUAjoLCC4QgAQQsQMQgwE6CAgAEIAEELEDOgsILhCABBCxAxDUAjoFCC4QgAQ6BwgjELECECdKBAhBGABKBAhGGAFQ2wVYljpg6zxoBnAAeACAAd8BiAHBEZIBBjAuMTAuMpgBAKABAbABFMgBCrgBAsABAdoBBggBEAEYAQ&sclient=gws-wiz-serp)**
/pəˈrəʊkɪəl/*adjective*

having a limited or narrow outlook or scope.

*"parochial attitudes"*

Answer (score 2):

I think ***[narrow-minded](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/narrow-minded)***   may fit your context:

> - lacking tolerance, breadth of view,
> - having a biased or illiberal viewpoint; bigoted, intolerant, or prejudiced

The Free Dictionary

Comment: Yep. another good word similar to that one is "myopic" https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/myopic

Comment: A bit of your own words explaining why you think this would improve this answer. Just citing a dictionary isn’t all that useful.

Answer (score 1):

I’d suggest *[close-minded](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/closed-minded)*, which is similar to *narrow-minded* but has more of the flavor of stubbornness. You might also consider *inflexible* and even *pigheaded*.

Answer (score 0):

*Naysayer* or *resister*: Someone with an aggressively negative attitude. -- [WordWeb](http://www.wordwebonline.com/en/NAYSAYER)

Answer (score 0):

I believe *condescending* is the correct word.

Comment: Why do you feel that way? Please use your own words to explain.

Comment: I use condescending because in the example used, Jack's attempt at answering the question was brushed aside in a condescending manner.  His answer was not required, it was dismissed out of hand in a way that demonstrates Tom's feeling of superiority.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps *derisive*,

> expressing or causing contemptuous ridicule or scorn : expressing or causing derision ([Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/derisive))

Or maybe *scornful*,

> showing or feeling scorn for someone or something ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/scornful))
>
> full of scorn : CONTEMPTUOUS ([Merriam-Webster)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/scornful)

Answer (score -1):

In the context of the example you have given, I would suggest [*flippant*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/flippant).

Comment: Why would you suggest that? Please use your own words to supply a supporting argument. One-word answers that merely cite dictionaries or have no supporting text are not answers at all.